# Chaining async functions doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to chain two async functions but it seems that the second one is being executed before the first one.
Here is my code

```
function performAction(e) {
const ZIP = document.getElementById('zip').value;
const fellings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
console.log(`${baseURL}${ZIP},us&appid=${key}`);
getWeather(baseURL, ZIP, key,).then((data) => {
    postData('/addweather', {temperature: data.main.temp ,date:newDate, userResponse: fellings })
}).then(
    updateUI()
)}
```

and This is getWeather()

```
const getWeather = async(baseURL, ZIP, key) => {
let URL = `${baseURL}${ZIP}&appid=${key}`;
const res = await fetch(URL)
try{
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}catch(error){
    console.log("error", error);
}}
```

and this is postData() which is supposed to execute after the getWeather function is excuted but it isn't.

```
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {}) => {
console.log(`This is what we fetch ${data.temperature}`);
console.log(`This is what we fetch ${data.date}`);
console.log(`This is what we fetch ${data.userResponse}`);
  const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
 // Body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
  body: JSON.stringify(data), 
});
try {
    const newData = await response.json();
    console.log(`This is the new Data ${newData.temperature}`);
    return newData;
}catch(error){
  console.log("error", error);
}}
```

and this is updateUI()

```
const updateUI = async () => {
const request = await fetch('/getweather');
try{
  const allData = await request.json();
  console.log('Get request');
        document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = allData.date;
        document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = allData.temperature;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = allData.userResponse;
}catch(error){
  console.log("error", error);
}}
```

What happens is that the UI gets updated first so it gets the value of undefined for the first time, and when I reload the page and enter new data the UI get's updated with the data from last time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise returned from `postData`:

```
getWeather(baseURL, ZIP, key,).then((data) => {
   return postData('/addweather', {temperature: data.main.temp ,date:newDate, userResponse: fellings })
}).then(() => {
   return updateUI()
})
```

Another way you could write this is like this:

```
async function run() {
   await getWeather(baseURL, ZIP, key)
   await postData('/addweather', {temperature: data.main.temp ,date:newDate, userResponse: fellings })
   await updateUI()
}
```

Comment: When I do this it throws an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'`  The return just works with `postData()` with no problems but it doesn't with `updateUI()`

Comment: Your async `run()` function makes no sense because data is not defined. Just sayin.

Comment: `data` could be defined in the closure, but my intent here is to show how you could use `async/await` instead

Answer (score -1):

your `postData()` is also an async function. Therefore you have to await this aswell:

```js
getWeather(baseURL, ZIP, key,).then(async (data) => {
    await postData('/addweather', {temperature: data.main.temp ,date:newDate, userResponse: fellings })
}).then(
    updateUI()
)}
```

I didn't have done javascript in a while, but i guess it is  more clear in this way:

```js
const performAction = async (e) => {
const ZIP = document.getElementById('zip').value;
const fellings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
console.log(`${baseURL}${ZIP},us&appid=${key}`);
try{
const data = await getWeather(baseURL, ZIP, key,);
const postData= await postData('/addweather', {temperature: data.main.temp ,date:newDate, userResponse: fellings });
} catch(e) {
console.log(e)
} finally {
    updateUI();
}
```

Also you dont have to await the parsing of the json and the try catch should contain your request:

```js
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {}) => {
console.log(`This is what we fetch ${data.temperature}`);
console.log(`This is what we fetch ${data.date}`);
console.log(`This is what we fetch ${data.userResponse}`);
try {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
 // Body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
  body: JSON.stringify(data), 
});

    const newData = response.json();
    console.log(`This is the new Data ${newData.temperature}`);
    return newData;
}catch(error){
  console.log("error", error);
}}
```

Comment: using your second example it now throws this error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'postData' before initialization
    at HTMLButtonElement.performAction`

Comment: and using your first example doesn't make any difference it also updates the UI before posting the data. This is really weird I don't know what's happening

Comment: Still, unfortunately, doesn't work and does the same behavior

Comment: @MarwanElgendy yeah because you return the data without saving it somewhere:
`
const data = await postData('/addweather', {temperature: data.main.temp ,date:newDate, userResponse: fellings });
console.log(data);
`

Comment: I actually save the data in an object in my server-side code, then in `updateUI` i nake a fetch request to get that data from the object, but it always makes the get request in `updateUI` before the POST request in `postData`